# suppress output of hping in Linux

Tags: bash, stdout

I wish to suppress all output to stdout (console) from hping3 from a bash script, but everything I try results in the statistics still being displayed, even tho the individual ping results are suppressed.

I've tried redirecting different ways, command line switch '-q' and nothing works.

Ideas?

```
hping3 10.1.1.1 -c 1 -q > \dev\null
hping3 10.1.1.1 -c 1 -q > logfile.txt
hping3 10.1.1.1 -c 1 -q 1>\dev\null
```

All result in the following to the console:

```
--- 10.1.1.1 hping statistic ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 1.1/1.1/1.1 ms
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what methods of redirection you've tried?  Sending stdout and stderr to `/dev/null` should quiet it down.

Comment: The correct syntax is `hping ... > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mark-wagner said, the correct syntax is

```
hping3 10.1.1.1 -c 1 -q >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This redirects standard output to a bit-bucket file called `/dev/null`, and then redirects standard error to the same place.

If this was insufficient (for example, output not on standard error or standard out) then you could do this:

```
( hping3 10.1.1.1 -c 1 -q ) >/dev/null
```

This should work, no matter where the output is directed - I think.

Comment: This put me on the alternate track of: hping3 10.1.1.1 -c 1 2> /dev/null, which displays the packet results, but not the summary statistics at the end. Thank you everyone.

Comment: This article helped to clearify it
https://securitythoughts.wordpress.com/2015/04/08/understanding-bash-stdout-stderr-using-hping3/